# Webgl is not working

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, lubuntu, firefox

I am currently using Lubuntu 20.04 LTS.
I want to use some websites which require webgl support. But in firefox browser webgl is not supported. I checked for `webgl.disabled` in `about:config` but it was set to `false`. Then I checked in `about:support`. In graphics section I found:

```
...
WebGL 1 Driver Renderer: WebGL creation failed: 
                         * WebglAllowWindowsNativeGl:false restricts context creation on this system.
                         * Exhausted GL driver options.
...
...
WebGL 2 Driver Renderer: WebGL creation failed: 
                         * AllowWebgl2:false restricts context creation on this system.
...
```

Then I toggled `webgl.force-enabled` option to `true` but it also didn't worked. And this time in graphics section of `about:support` page I found:

```
...
WebGL 1 Driver Renderer: WebGL creation failed: 
                         * tryNativeGL
                         * Exhausted GL driver options.
...
...
WebGL 2 Driver Renderer: WebGL creation failed: 
                         * tryNativeGL
                         * Exhausted GL driver options.
...
```

Here is my system information:

```
System:    Host: edm Kernel: 5.8.0-50-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: LXQt 0.14.1 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: N/A model: N/A serial: <superuser/root required> 
           BIOS: American Megatrends v: 080014 date: 05/12/2014 
CPU:       Dual Core: Intel Core2 Duo E4500 type: MCP speed: 1238 MHz 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: intel unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa 
           resolution: 1024x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel G33 v: 1.4 Mesa 20.2.6 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet driver: r8169 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 74.53 GiB used: 14.32 GiB (19.2%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD800BD-22MRA1 size: 74.53 GiB 
Info:      Processes: 161 Uptime: 24m Memory: 1.93 GiB used: 855.0 MiB (43.2%) Shell: bash 
           inxi: 3.0.38
```

I also checked for additional drivers to install using the "Software Sources" application, but I found nothing there.

I previously faced the same issue in Xubuntu 20.04. I switched to linuxmint 20.1 and there was no such issue, all the websites using webgl worked perfectly fine. How should I fix it? How do I enable webgl support in my system?

Thanks...

Comment: I get the same output in `about:support` in Firefox 100.0.2, an installation that annoyingly updates itself on Ubuntu. I'm pretty sure [WebGL](https://get.webgl.org/) used to work there. But I also keep a separate installation of Firefox 66.0.5 and there WebGL works fine and reports my Nvida card and driver. WebGL also works in my Chrome 102.0.5005.61.

Comment: I've just tried a standalone [Firefox 100.0.2](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/100.0.2/linux-x86_64/en-GB/) and WebGL works there. So it doesn't work in the package maintained by Ubuntu, in my case `100.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`.

Comment: I created a fresh profile with `firefox -P` and it solved the problem.